# Django Rest Framework - Endpoint outside permission

Tags: python, django

Im using DRF to build my backend endpoint.
I have a viewset protected by isAuthenticated permission_class.

```
class SubnetViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Every endpoint requires autnetication and it works perfectly.
Unfortunally, one endpoint of this viewset must be accessible without authentication.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
def endpoint_free(self, request):
    [...]
```

Is there a way to exclude only this endpoint without create a new ViewSet. I have found nothing on official Docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in `permission_classes` argument:

```py
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny])
def endpoint_free(self, request):
    ...
```